# JavaScript : Remove duplicate element value from array without nested for loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, for-loop

I have an array, something like below,

```
   const array = [
      {
        "name": "Port 01",
        "portsActual": [ 
          "Hong Kong",
          "Ningbo, CN",
          "Hong Kong"     // remove this duplicate
        ]
      }
    ]
```

My effort :

```
for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    const emt = array[index];
    let uniqueArray = []
    if(emt["portsActual"].length > 0) {
        for (let j = 0; j < emt["portsActual"].length; j++) {
            const nestEmt = emt["portsActual"][j];
            if( !uniqueArray.includes(nestEmt)) {
                uniqueArray.push(nestEmt)
            } 
        }
    }
    emt["portsActual"] = uniqueArray
}
```

Is any other way to get that kind of output without nested for loop?

Comment: Show some effort, what have you tried?

Comment: `let me know the best possible way` like to walk over your source dataset, identify duplicates and remove it would work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

you could do with `Array#forEach` to iterate the array.Then Apply  [`Array#filter`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwilgKWS86bWAhXFK48KHQk5B5AQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Ffilter&usg=AFQjCNHTybPLK3GeAl_0DVx-FLbAD2mWtw) for filter the duplicate values

```js
var arr = [{ "name": "Port 01", "portsActual": [ "Hong Kong", "Ningbo, CN", "Hong Kong", ] }, { "name": "Port 02", "portsActual": [ "Kobe, JP", "Osaka, JP", "Osaka, JP" ] } ]

arr.forEach(a => {
  a.portsActual = a.portsActual.filter((i, k) => a.portsActual.indexOf(i) == k)
})

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: You are welcome .If you satisfied with my answer.Please tick as an answer.it's helpful for a future visitors @RahulTank

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple for loop to check through each of the keys and filter them out individually to check for duplicates.

```
 function checkNestedThenDelete(obj /*, level1, level2, ... levelN*/) {
          var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

          for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            if (!obj || !obj.hasOwnProperty(args[i])) {
             obj[args[i]]= "";
              return true;
            }
            obj = obj[args[i]];
          }
          return false;
        }

        var test = {level1:{level2:{level3:'level3'}} };

        checkNestedThenDelete(test, 'level1', 'level2', 'level3'); // true
        checkNestedThenDelete(test,'level1', 'level2', 'foo'); // false
```

Answer (score -1):

intuitive solution:

```
var arr = [1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,5]
var arr2 =[];
        for(var i=0; i < (arr.length-1); i++){
                    if (arr2.indexOf(arr[i]) > -1 || arr[i] != arr[i+1]){                       
                        //Do Nothing and move on to the next set
                    }
                    else{
                        arr2.push(arr[i]);                  
                    }
        }
```